# CMake project structure with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cmake, build, project

I've been at this for hours and I'm so lost. This is what my project structure looks like, very basic.

```
Project
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - src
        - main.cpp
        - class.cpp
        - anotherClass.cpp
    - include
        - class.h
        - anotherClass.h
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project(Project)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

When I build a Visual Studio project in the "Filter View" or whatever it's called, all headers are shown under "Header files" and all source files are shown under "Source files". That's fine, but the problem is that my actual folder structure is nonexistent. All source and header files are bunched up together and it doesn't look nice. How do I make the build have the project structure above?

Comment: Isn't that file structure exactly what you described above?

Comment: I would like CMake to build a VS project with that structure. If i open the solution in VS all the files are bunched together

Comment: But your structure has headers and bodies separated and that's what you got in Visual Studio right? Perhaps I read wrong...

Comment: Add a screenshot of your current project structure to make it clear what structure you are using.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I assume by "Filter View" you mean "Solution Explorer".*

The [`USE_FOLDERS` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/USE_FOLDERS.html) just determines, if the targets should be grouped into folders in the Visual Studio solution explorer, and even if you activate it, you'll still need to use the `CMAKE_FOLDER` variable or the `FOLDER` target property to specify the folder for targets.

If you want the source files to shown in a directory structure, you need to use the [`source_group` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html) to accomplish this.

```
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    FILES ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES}
)
```

Setting the `USE_FOLDERS` property is not needed for this to work.

---

Unrelated note:

```
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)
```

Is just wrong in this case, even though it does not break anything here: `target_link_directories` is used to specify directories where the linker looks for libraries and there are no library files in the `include` directory; furthermore I'd try to avoid specifying link directories, if possible.

---

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

It's imho preferrable to specify this kind of information on a per-target basis:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)
```